# wget: Follow custom URL attributes

Tags: wget

wget is a great tool to make a quick snapshot of a small site. As far as I know (I really hope I just couldn't find it in `wget --help`), wget can follow well-known HTML URL attributes only, like `<a href=...`, `<img src=...` and so on. However, sometimes a particular site might use non-standard attributes that represent real URLs that do not look like URLs for wget. Let' say, if a site has a "static" gallery with zoomed images, a particular image page might have something like this:

```
<div zoomed_img="/gallery/image.jpg">
    <img src="/gallery/image_small.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Thus, wget ignores the `zoomed_img` attribute with `/gallery/image.jpg`. My wget command is:

```
wget --recursive \
    --domains domain \
    --no-parent \
    --page-requisites \
    --no-clobber \
    --html-extension \
    --convert-links \
    http://domain/gallery
```

Is it possible to make wget follow custom URL HTML attributes?

Comment: did you try the --follow-tags command ?

Comment: @Thomas just checked it. Specifying the `div` tag explicitly as `--follow-tags=a,div,img` resulted in the same effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

wget (at least 1.16.3) does not allow a user to specify custom attributes. There has been a [suggestion](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2014-09/msg00006.html) to extend the the `--follow-tags` option with a syntax like `--follow-tags=a/href`, but nobody followed up on that.

If you do not mind applying a quick hack to wget to support your scenario, see [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/wget.git/commit/src/html-url.c?id=6a2d67b5836a6f1b9c989968a5392ff3511bc1f9) for the work needed to add custom tags or attributes.

Alternatively, you can write a post-processor yourself.

Comment: Thanks for interesting links. Yes, I've checked out the latest wget source code, and wget seems to have nothing related to custom attributes (my wget version is _1.17.1.11-b305_). As far as I understand C code, `html_url.c` and wget, `--follow-tags` is an intersection filter against `interesting_tags` initially filled with `known_tags` (thus there could be no way to add new tags? -- probably that was a reason why the suggestion was not followed up). I'll try to add the `div/zoomed_img` pair myself. Regarding post-processor: unfortunately I was looking for a Windows-friendly solution too.

Comment: I would like to accept this answer, as it really reveals that wget is unable to fulfill the request. I had the same idea of patching wget, and I just added `TAG_DIV`, and registered it in `known_tags` and `tag_url_attributes` locally. The local version of wget mirrored all I needed. Just 3 lines of code is not a big issue. I wish I could know C enough to add the support for tag/attribute pairs myself.

Answer (score 1):

As **wget** doesn't allow to follow **data-src**, my solution was to use a proxy to replace all the **"data-src" by "src"** on the fly.

Using https://mitmproxy.org/ for example, with the following script:

```py
"""
Fix the lazy loader SRC.
"""
from mitmproxy import http

def response(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    if flow.response and flow.response.content:
        flow.response.content = flow.response.content.replace(
            b"data-src", b"src"
        )
```

Running the proxy:

```bash
mitmdump -s src.py --ssl-insecure
```

Telling wget to use the proxy:

```bash
wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=localhost:8080 -e https_proxy=localhost:8080 --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --no-parent --progress=dot --recursive --level=6 --reject-regex "(.*)\?(.*)" --no-check-certificate https://website.com/
```

The result is that wget will mirror the whole website by passing throug the local proxy, which is editing the HTML on the fly before wget can read it. So images url are discovered.