# Can wget download reveal.js image assets?

Tags: command-line, wget, images

In using the `wget` command below,

```
$ wget \
     --recursive \
     --no-clobber \
     --page-requisites \
     --html-extension \
     --convert-links \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --domains grantmlong.com \
     --no-parent \
         grantmlong.com/teaching/index.html
```

I have been trying to download all content from a professor's [course page](https://grantmlong.com/teaching/).  For some reason, while much of the image content for the remainder of the site is being downloaded correctly, the images for the [reveal.js](https://revealjs.com/#/) lecture slides are not being downloaded.

For example, if, on my local computer, I navigate to `grantmlong.com/teaching/lectures/` and open `lecture1.html`, what appears for the third slide is [image]

Instead of this:[image]

On the website, I find that the image is located at `https://grantmlong.com/teaching/lectures/img/hbr.png`. If I navigate to the local `img` folder downloaded by `wget`, I see

```
cd grantmlong.com/teaching/lectures/img
ls -1
l10_f0.png
l10_f1.png
l10_f2.png
l10_f3.png
l10_f4.png
l10_f5b.png
l10_f5.png
l10_f6.png
l10_f7.png
l10_p1.png
l10_p2.png
l11_p1.png
l11_p2.png
l11_p3.png
l11_p4.png
l11_p5.png
l11_p6.png
l12_p1.png
l12_p2.png
l5_e1.png
l5_e2.png
l5_e3.png
l5_e4.png
l5_glm.png
l5_logreg.png
l5_p10.png
l5_p11.png
l5_p1a.png
l5_p1b.png
l5_p2.png
l5_p3.png
l5_p4.png
l5_p5.png
l5_p6.png
l5_p7.png
l5_p8.png
l5_p9.png
l5_reg_output_1.png
l5_reg_output_2.png
l5_reg_output_3.png
l5_reg_output_4.png
l5_reg_output.png
l6_accuracy.png
l6_confusion.png
l6_p1.png
l6_precision.png
l6_recall.png
l9_p1.png
l9_p2.png
l9_p3.png
l9_p4.png
l9_t1.png
l9_t2.png
l9_t3.png
l9_t4.png
l9_t5.png
```

`hbr.png` is nowhere to be found, which shows that the images in these reveal.js slides are not considered "page requisites" and are not being downloaded by `wget`.

What can I do to ensure these images are downloaded? Also, note that some of the images on the reveal.js slides come from 3rd party sites like [giphy](https://giphy.com/). How can I ensure that this external content is downloaded while keeping the option `--domains grantmlong.com` true for all pages that aren't reveal.js slides?

Comment: This might help: https://askubuntu.com/a/547126/612676

Comment: Hrm, it seems like a lot of the tutorials for phantom.js are for scraping text or images, but not for recreating the entire site as a whole. It also says on the phantom.js site that it is no longer under active development. Maybe I can try chrome headless with selenium, but I still don't see how I can save a mirror of the reveal.js slides with these tools. Are you aware of any tutorials/documentation that might help me save these slides locally in such a way that I can open them within my browser and view them as if they were still online?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'm not very familiar with web scraping, so I don't have much to offer. I did check on that PhantomJS project though, and it looks like you can still download and use the last good version. There's a simple script here that may be useful in downloading the site: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34175652/6216002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching, I found a (hacky) solution to the problem of downloading an archive of reveal.js slides. On the codimd github, the user "zeigerpuppy" posted [the following response](https://github.com/hackmdio/codimd/issues/545):

> I have found a way to save an archive of a slide presentation built
>   with codimd.  I had some trouble getting wget to pull the images from
>   the presentation  (I think because the links to the images are in
>   markdown).
>
> So, it's a three step process but it's quick and works well.  Let's
>   say you have a slide show at https://codimd.server.net/p/S1PIjfhM8#/
>
> 1. use `wget` to grab the files and the requisites (.css and .js)
>
>    - your presentation will end up as `p/S1PIjfhM8.html`
>
> `
>
> ```
> wget   --recursive   --no-clobber   --page-requisites   \
> --html-extension   --convert-links   \
> --domains codimd.server.net \
> https://codimd.server.net/p/S1PIjfhM8#/
> ```
>
> 1. use the firefox plugin: [Image Picka](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-picka/?src=search)
>
>    - use the save pattern: `Image_Picka/uploads/${name}${ext}`
>    - it gets all images on page (including .svg)
>    - move the images to the folder called `uploads` in the web archive root
> 2. we need to use `sed` to change the links in the html file to relative links so that they point to the images
>
> `
>
> ```
> cd p
> sed -i .bak 's|/uploads/upload_|../uploads/upload_|g' S1PIjfhM8.html
> ```
>
> Then you'll have a full copy of the slides that you can run offline. 
>   It's also good for archive purposes.
>
> It'd be great if something like this was also built into the codimd
>   program under the save options, maybe `save slides`.

I took a similar approach, although I didn't do the last step with `sed`. Instead, I used Image Picka to download all the images missed by `wget` and I put them in the `grantmlong.com/teaching/lectures/img/` directory on my local `wget` archive. That made most of the image content appear in the slides.

Although the gifs from 3rd party sites won't load, those were mostly aesthetic (no important equations or diagrams were in .gif format.) So, I'm happy that I can view the most essential content offline.

Answer (score 1):

No it can't.

The file hbr.png is referenced by a custom attribute **data-src** on the img tag.

As explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/258850/181544), there is no way for wget to follow custom attributes.